# NHibernate config properties in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I am considering using Fluent NHibernate for my project and I haven't found any documentation on whether FH supports NHibernate settings such as show_sql and prepare_sql.  I could live without show_sql in a pinch, but prepare_sql is important for ensuring good performance at run time.

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to configure these settings in Fluent NHibernate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(ConfigureDatabase())
    .Mappings(ConfigureMapping)
    .ExposeConfiguration(ModifyConfiguration)
    .BuildConfiguration();
```

And now in `ModifyConfiguration` method you have plain `NHibernate`'s `Configuration` object to modify

```
private void ModifyConfiguration(Configuration configuration)
{
    // set parameters here like this:
    configuration.Properties["show_sql"] = "true";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the settings are exposed through the fluent API.

See here for examples: [Database Configuration](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Database_configuration)

Anything that isn't supported through specific fluent calls can be set by manipulating the native NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration object. Either way you can do everything in code that you can with the configuration file.